# Command not found when executed as sudo, but works after "sudo su"

Tags: linux, bash, npm, permissions, sudo

If i try to run this command bash respond with not found error:

```
$ npm -v
-bash: npm: command not found
```

with sudo also:

```
$ sudo npm -v
sudo: npm: command not found
```

but works when I run first a "sudo su":

```
$ sudo su
# npm -v
6.10.3
```

Why this happens? how can I fix it to works with sudo command?

Comment: sudo does not inherit its command environment, the root's user $PATH value could be different from the one's launching the sudo command

Comment: statement mentioned by @franzisk is correct, however  I sometimes use `sudo -i <command>` as a workaround in `SLES` . Not sure if it will work in your dirtro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **@franzisk** pointed out, this can be issue of the `$PATH` for the npm.

Try to do `echo $PATH` both as **normal** user and **super** user. Also run `which npm` as superuser. If you see any difference (for example, path to npm is not in the normal user path) make changes to your `PATH` variable accordingly.